# Mac pausing bluetooth headset used by another device

Tags: macos, bluetooth, headphones

I try to use my bluetooth headset (Jabra Elite Active 75t) with both my Macbook (MacOS 10.15.5 19F101) and my Android phone. If I pause all the sounds on Mac and try to play any music on the phone, the reproduction will stop immediately as if pause signal is sent.

This can also be reproduced with another bluetooth speaker.

Any idea how can I work around the bug?

Comment: Any sound your computer makes  whether a system sound (i.e. an alert) or something from media will cause the media to stop playing on your other device.  What you have to do is temporarily disconnect from the device you're not listening to.  This happens to me all the time on my iPad and iPhone.

Comment: I'd really love a solution for that. My multi-point bluetooth device is pretty much useless on macOS with this wonder "feature".

Answer (score 1):

Any sound your computer makes  whether a system sound (i.e. an alert) or something from media will cause the media to stop playing on your other device.  What you have to do is temporarily disconnect from the device you're not listening to.  In macOS, just click on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar, select your audio device and select *Disconnect.*

[image: Bluetooth Audio Disconnect]

It's only temporary and you and reconnect any time by going to the same menu and clicking *Connect*.

This happens to me all the time on my iPad and iPhone.  It's not really a bug, but a limitation.  The computer/iPad/iPhone isn't stopping the music, it's the headphone - it's assuming that the "new" sound coming from the device is what should have priority so it sends a pause signal (like you hit the button on the headset manually) to the app playing the music/video/whatever.

I also suggest having all system sounds play through the internal speakers and not the audio device you listen to for videos, music, etc.

[image]

I got this information from Sennheiser  support because any small noise my iPhone made would pause the music or podcast I was listening to on my iPad.

Comment: This is not a solution, but rather a workaround for their bug.

There's nothing that plays any sound on Mac currently, but I'm still able to reproduce it. Also, when I can reproduce it, it behaves like there's something continuously playing on Mac (so, the music stops every time I hit play on my phone) and not like there's been one notification. Also, completely muting the system doesn't help either

Comment: Another funny symptom is that disconnecting and immediately connecting fixes the issue for some time.

Comment: Same here. This is annoying as hell!

Comment: +1 for making me understand the real problem. But certainly, not a solution. It seems to be intermittent, different notifications from the same app sometimes interrupt the music, sometimes they don't (within the same "session", I mean, without me touching or changing anything after hitting Play button again in Music after it gets interrupted the previous time). Yes, very annoying.